Unpivot columns with multiple relevant rows with headers. PowerQuery M language | Multiple Unpivot simultaneously
I have a table which have multiple headers in the rows that I want to keep when I unpivot my table, but I couldn't find a way to unpivot it as needed.
Please find below the example of the original table





Actuals
Actuals
Plan
Plan






FY20
FY20
FY21
FY21


Country
Owner
1/1/2020
1/1/2020
1/1/2020
1/1/2020


France
Richard
100
150
80
160


France
Martin
120
140
130
140


France
Pierre
50
100
50
80



Below is what I want to achieve (unpivot the 4 columns, but keep the headers in the rows as new columns)



Country
Owner
Version
Year
Date
Value




France
Richard
Actuals
FY20
1/1/2020
100


France
Richard
Actuals
FY21
1/1/2020
150


France
Richard
Plan
FY20
1/1/2020
80


France
Richard
Plan
FY21
1/1/2020
160


France
Martin
Actuals
FY20
1/1/2020
120


France
Martin
Actuals
FY21
1/1/2020
140


France
Martin
Plan
FY20
1/1/2020
130


France
Martin
Plan
FY21
1/1/2020
140


France
Pierre
Actuals
FY20
1/1/2020
50


France
Pierre
Actuals
FY21
1/1/2020
100


France
Pierre
Plan
FY20
1/1/2020
50


France
Pierre
Plan
FY21
1/1/2020
80



I believe this can only be achieved with the custom code, but I'm not familiar with it apart of the standard functionalities.
Thank you in advance and please let me know if any other info is relevant.
[Edit: The date in the table for Actuals should be FY20 and FY21, and the year should change as well, same for the Plan, should be FY20 and FY21 and the year should change as well. I won't change now as that would change the answers that solved my issue of converting the multiplied headers in the rows to columns]
Cheers

I think there is an error in your sample table. The first table should not have the same FY for both Actuals columns, no?

@teylyn you are absolutely correct, it was supposed to be the following year, and the plan should have been FY20 and then FY21 as well.

let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
NewNames=List.Transform(List.Zip({
        Record.FieldValues(Source{0}),
        Record.FieldValues(Source{1}),
        List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(Source{2}), each Text.From(_)
        )}), each Text.Combine(_,":")),
Rename=Table.RenameColumns(Table.Skip(Source,3),List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source),NewNames})),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Rename, {"Country", "Owner"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Version", "Year", "Date"}),
Touchup=Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Version", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveItems(Text.ToList(_),{"0".."9"}))}}),
Touchup2=Table.TransformColumns(Touchup,{{"Date", each Date.From(Number.From(_))}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Touchup2,{{"Date", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"



Here is one way of doing this in POWER QUERY



First convert your source data as Structured References aka Tables but note when hitting CTRL+T to convert the same, do not select My Table As Headers.
Now open a blank query from --> Data Tab --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query.
The above opens up the Power Query window, now from Home Tab in the same window, click on Advanced Editor and paste the following code, remember to change the table name as per your suit.


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    First3Rows = Table.FirstN(Source,3),
    Rows2Columns = Table.Transpose(First3Rows),
    Merged = Table.CombineColumns(Rows2Columns,{"Column1", "Column2","Column3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    Columns2Rows = Table.Transpose(Merged),
    Combined = Table.Combine({Columns2Rows,Table.RemoveFirstN(Source,3)}),
    PromotedHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(Combined, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    UnpivotedOtherColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(PromotedHeaders, {"  Country", "  Owner"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    SplitColumnbyDelimiter = Table.SplitColumn(UnpivotedOtherColumns, "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Version", "Year", "Date"}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(SplitColumnbyDelimiter, {{"Date", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "_"), type text}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter",{{"  Country", type text}, {"  Owner", type text}, {"Version", type text}, {"Year", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"



I think there is an error in your sample table. The blue table should not have the same FY for both Actuals columns, no?

@teylyn madam, I have copied the sample from OP. I have not checked. I was busy in trying to resolve. OP should clarify that out, but you are right

Sorry, I didn't see it was your answer. I just saw my screen flash and the text appear as Excel. I thought it was the question.  I added the comment to the question now, too.

Thank you so much for the explained steps, this worked well, I just had to change the Date type into text before merging the 3 column steps, because I was getting an error. By adding that it worked perfectly !
Please find below the step I added between the 3rd step (Rows2Columns) and 4th (Merged).
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows2Columns,{{"Column3", type text}}),


@teylyn is right in his point, and thanks for pointing that. I won't change the initial table to not change the whole input and output. In the end, both answers were correct and thank you for your help.

@MartimOnFire not sure why i dont require to change the data type it works for me.

Understood why got error, while i didnt because i copied data from your post which is in text format and PQ read it as general.

Ohh brilliant, that makes sense @MayukhBhattacharya  thanks a ton for the help and contribution
